# Cpanel doesnt show database but it does exist

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have a problem with Cpanel, or atleast with my database, because i cant see my database trough either cpanel,mysql databases or phpmyadmin but when i tried to run a import sql script it states that the database exists. How can i access my database, i have heard some databasemapping resets on cpanel level but the problem is that i cant access the server on any way(only my site via FTP ofcourse).

It looks like i dont have permission, also my firstly created (head mysql account) is gone, or atleast i cant login with the same credentials as before. Whenever i try to add an mysql user it says completed(user created succesfully) but when looking at all users there aren't any users stated.

Sounds strange doesn't it?

I hope someone knows the answer, i need the database back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/) for importing and exporting data via ftp. Please try.

Comment: It looks like i dont have permission, also my firstly created (head mysql account) is gone, or atleast i cant login with the same credentials as before. Whenever i try to add an mysql user it says completed(user created succesfully) but when looking at all users there aren't any users stated.